# CiviCRM adds Itemid parameter to a URL in scheduled reminders

Tags: joomla, mailing, scheduled-reminders, urls

Let's say we have a scheduled reminder that includes a URL example.com/more/page
The civicrm_mailing_trackable_url table record has the correct example.com/more/page value in the url field. But, when someone clicks on the link (which CiviCRM changes to, e.g., https://example.com/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/mailing/url&Itemid=2252&u=14606&qid=5235776) in the said email, it redirects to example.com/more/page?Itemid=2252 (menu item id 2252 is the home page).

So, it appears Civi injects the "&Itemid=2252" parameter in the URL, which is terrible as it's the home page, and we definitely don't want to send the user there in most cases.

Any way to remove this Itemid injection? Thx.

(This is on Joomla 4.4.2 and CiviCRM 5.69.2.)

Comment: resolved this temporarily via a work-around (but it's a bit butch... would love to find the real solution) - added the following to .htaccess:

RewriteCond %{query_string} ^Itemid=2252

RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]